If there were no Original Sin, would've everyone been married?
Benedict Ashley, O.P., Spiritual Direction in the Dominican Tradition p. 50 claims:

Naturally speaking, the human species is divided equally into male and female, so that every human can find a partner and form a marriage, and if there had been no fall into sin, naturally all persons would have married.

Is this true? Would've everyone married if there were no Original Sin?
It seems not, as isn't celibacy equally natural as being married?
What did Catholic fathers or doctors of the Church have to say about this?

I can't see the connection. Anyway, until recently I was very hard to live alone. Nowadays we can thanks to electricity, refrigeration, appliances, supermarkets and delivery, but in ancient time you must to produce everything by yourself, including clothes and food. And your children were your only support in your old age.

"isn't celibacy equally natural" is presented as a rhetorical question with an assumed answer of "yes". But really, celibacy isn't natural; it's something that must be enforced, whether by oneself of by society.

In my country there is a saying: "if the sky falls down, we all have a blue hat", meaning it is often without sense to speculate about "what if" questions. I think this question about marriage and original sin falls in that category. I know this may not sound like an honest answer to the question, but I suggest the question is unanswerable. We cannot know what would have happend if what happened hadn't happened.

@RayButterworth Marriage has to be "enforced", too. Married people have to constantly will to remain married, just like celibate people who've vowed to remain unmarried have to constantly will to remain unmarried. But my question isn't about whether celibacy is natural or not; it's about whether, in the state of innocent, had Adam conceived offspring, they would've all married.

@Geremia says "Married people have to constantly will to remain married. I can't speak for everyone, but that's certainly not true for the people I know. The desire for sex is natural; the desire for celibacy is not.

@RayButterworth The desire for God is natural, too, for everyone. (And celibates devote themselves more singularly to God.)

In 2022 there were 4 billion men and 3.95 billion women.  50 million men with no possible marriage partner.  Are you asking whether, in a world without sin, the ratio would be 1:1?

@MikeBorden No, I'm asking if everyone would've married. The ratio could still be 1:1 even if only some fraction (< 100%) of the world's population married and the others remained celibate. (Your question seems to be about whether there would've been involuntary celibates or not.)

Also consider that when all is consummated and sin is done away with we will neither marry nor be given in marriage.  Marriage is a picture of Christ and the Church so, in a sense, even though it was instituted before sin, it was instituted with sin in mind.

@MikeBorden True, Mt. 22:30 would seem to show that in the state of innocence, everyone would've been celibate/unmarried.

"in the state of innocence, everyone would've been celibate/unmarried" - unless I'm missing your meaning, this seems clearly inconsistent with Genesis 1:27-28 and 2:23-24.

@user111403 Well, by "everyone" I mean Adam (or Adam & Eve), but yes it wouldn't make sense for everyone to be celibate, unless God had a different way of bringing new people into existence besides the natural way of sexual intercourse (e.g., creating them like he created Adam); but sexual reproduction is part of man's nature, and God doesn't make anything superfluous. (cf. "Would God allow all of humanity to be celibate?")

I don't see why this is downvoted... it is a religious question. you picked a denomination, and while being somewhat speculative... there is nothing wrong with that. Considering that I've pointed out that "if the fall didn't happen, Christ would still have come to connect human and divine nature together" which is also speculation (even if saints said it)

@Wyrsa Indeed. St. Thomas Aquinas asks such speculative questions regarding the condition of Adam's offspring had he not sinned (Summa Theologiæ I q. 99, q. 100, q. 101).

@MikeBorden See my answer below. The answer to your question is yes, there would've been equal numbers of males and females (it follows from everyone marrying and there being no polygamy, which God only permitted to sufficiently populate the world after death entered it).

St. Thomas Aquinas answers this question in the context of addressing Quodlibetal Questions III, q. 11 posed to him: "If the first human being had not sinned, would an equal number of males and females have been born?"
Quodlibet III, q. 11 arg.:

According to Augustine, in paradise marriage would have been honorable and its bed undefiled [Eph. 5:27].174 Hence, no one would have been abstinent. Rather, everyone would have used marriage to fulfill the command the Lord gave to the first human beings: Increase and multiply and fill the earth, as it says in Genesis 1.175 But in the state of innocence, no man would have had more than one wife, and no woman would have had more than one husband, nor would any men or women have suffered death. Therefore, it follows that an equal number of males and females would have been born.174. Augustine, Literal Commentary on Genesis IX, 3 [pp. 378-9].175. Genesis 1:28.

Answer found by searching for "=matrimonio * =statu innocentiae" in St. Thomas's works.

I am sorry for not being able to quote any Catholic father or doctor of the Church in support of the following points. The inputs have  specific reference to the quote from Benedict   Ashley, as cited  by OP:
Kerala State in Southern India has male- female ratio of 1000:1084 which is better than the national average of 1000:940. There are two reasons : (i) Kerala has 18.4 per cent Christian population  and the citizens generally abide by the rules and regulations with regard to sustenance of  human life (ii) the state is at the top in terms of literacy, and the practice of female foeticide is rare.  The state stands as a proof that humankind as a whole is not designed to have male and female members in exactly equal proportion.
Any educated person can make out that it is the XX and XY chromosomes that decide the sex of the child. While woman contributes  only X from her side, man's sperms belong to  either X or Y chromosome, the former being more in number but having less lifespan vis-a-vis the latter. Without human intervention, human population is tilted towards a higher ratio in favour of females.  It is another story why many societies have a ratio in favour of male members.
In theory, if each and every male member of a society where no pro- male child intervention happens, wants to marry , some will fall short of brides! Thankfully, there is no bar relating  to age, other than the one imposed by Goverment on minimum age for marriage , to curb marriages. To illustrate, Mr X,aged 60,can marry Ms.Y ,aged 23 , from subsequent generation.
Neither is there any rule, either Govt-imposed or religion-imposed, that  each marriageable adult should marry . There are many who remain bachelors and spinsters even if they do not join any religious order.
PS: St Paul in 1 Timothy 3:2 says that the Bishop should be ' husband of one wife ' . Does that somehow imply that polygamy was prevalent among Jews and early Christians ? Or, does St Paul only say that the Bishop should not be a bachelor ?
